# In the project generated thanks to VueCLI wanting to run the command "npm run serve" I got an error saying "Module build failed ..."

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I have created a new project in Vue CLI using the "vue create test" command. When everything was done correctly, I went to the project folder and launched the "npm run serve" command, the result of which is this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
Error: Can not find module '/home/revuex/Sites/test/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 636: 15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 562: 25)
    at Module.require (internal / modules / cjs / loader.js: 690: 17)
    at require (internal / modules / cjs / helpers.js: 25: 18)
    at Object.module.exports (/home/revuex/Sites/test/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js:170:23)
```

I use Window Linux Subsystem and latest version of Vue CLI and 8.11.2 Node.js.

Comment: Please use a more explicit title. Please read how to create an [mcve] instead of saying you have a vue project. Please post code as code instead of link to image. Please visit [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I did not change anything in the code. I generated a new project in vue cli, to work on it, and immediately ran "npm run serve" without any changes in the code and I received this error.

Comment: What do you mean by *not change anything in the code*? Which code? Which CLI guide are you trying to follow? Which commands did you type? Which version are you using? Did you read the guide on creating reproducible examples? Do you need assistance inn editing the question so as ton include the error log as text instead of link?

Comment: I have already changed the title and content. Are they correct now?

Comment: Yes. I removed my downvote. Thanks for taking the time to enhance the quality of your post.

Comment: @Revuex It looks like eslint-loader is [broken](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/eslint-loader/issues/282). When you see weird errors like this, it's always good to check the issue page for the project.